# How do I check if file was written to successfully?

Tags: c

I have written the function, don't know it that's correct but how do I return true and false using if condition?

**Function bool save_book(Book*, char*)**
**Input Parameters:** A pointer to a Book and a string representing a file name.
**Return Value:** Return true if the book's contents were stored to a file successfully. Otherwise false.
**Note** This function should create or open a file based on the file name and store each Line of the book in it.

**Below is my code**

```
bool save_book(Book *b, char* fileName){

FILE  *filePointer = fopen(fileName,"w");
for (int i = 0; i < pBook->lineCount; i++)
{
    fprintf(filePointer, "%s", b->lines[i]);
}
fclose(filePointer);

return true;
}
```

this is the struct I am using:

```
typedef struct _Book
{
   int characterCount;
   int lineCount;
   int maxLineCount;
   char **lines;
}Book;
```

Comment: Read documentation of [C IO functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)

Comment: Check whether the `fopen()` works; check whether each `fprintf()` works; check whether `fclose()` works.  If none of them report a problem, the chances are high that everything is OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There can still be caching on the OS and the cache can be lost when a latter access to the disk fails. To be save a sync is needed.

Comment: Which platform do you use?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: yes, and disk drives can be removed, and … That's why the chances are 'high', not 'absolute'. If you're using file streams, getting the relevant sync options set is fiddly — doable on POSIX systems, probably doable on Windows. There are different levels of sync-safety too, with different ramifications for system performance. It isn't clear whether describing such details would benefit the OP, though. A lot depends on what the requirements are, but for most people (programs) most of the time, checking the I/O operations is sufficient — but not for everyone all the tie.

Comment: Cant I just check if the file is null? is its null then it hasn't been written to. Is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: @shardul: Verifying that `filePointer != NULL` after the call to `fopen` is the most important check. That makes sure that the file was opened successfully. It is also possible that `fopen` will succeed and that `fprintf` will fail afterwards, but this is rather unlikely. Therefore, in my experience, it is always important to check the return value of `fopen`, but normally not necessary to check the return value of `fprintf`. Also, it is also normally not necessary to check `fclose`.

Comment: No, you absolutely must check the value returned by `fclose`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check every individual I/O operation.

To make it fun, they all return different things on error. [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) will return NULL. [`fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) will return a negative number. [`fclose`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) will return EOF.

Here it is annotated with a short list of what might go wrong at each step.

```
bool save_book(Book *b, char* fileName) {
    // Maybe the directory doesn't exist.
    // Maybe you don't have permission.
    // Maybe there's a disallowed character.
    // Maybe the disk is full.
    // Maybe it's a network drive and there's a network error.
    // Maybe the drive got unmounted.
    FILE  *filePointer = fopen(fileName,"w");
    if( filePointer == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b->lineCount; i++)
    {
        // Maybe the disk is full.
        // Maybe it's a network drive and there's a network error.
        // Maybe the drive got unmounted.
        if( fprintf(filePointer, "%s", b->lines[i]) < 0 ) {
            // Even though the filePointer variable will be automatically freed
            // the underlying file handle will not be automatically closed.
            // There's a limit to how many open file handles one can have open.
            // No need to check for error, we know something has already gone wrong.
            fclose(filePointer);
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Maybe the disk is full.
    // Maybe it's a network drive and there's a network error.
    // Maybe the drive got unmounted.
    if( fclose(filePointer) != 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In reality you probably don't need to check `fprintf`, checking `fclose` should catch the same errors. But if you're writing a very large and expensive file you might want to know if you ran out of disk space sooner rather than later.

You can also optionally print the error. Each of those functions will set the global [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) on failure. You can turn this into a human readable string with [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror).

```
    if( filePointer == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening '%s' for writing: %s", fileName, strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }
```

Note that rather than checking for an exact error code, I tend to check for that which is not the success code. Rather than `if( fclose(filePointer) == EOF )` I've checked for `if( fclose(filePointer) != 0 )`, the lack of a success code. This is a defense programming practice just in case the error is severe enough that it can't even return its correct error code (extremely unlikely in standard library code) or I didn't read the spec quite right.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Defensive programming validated! :)

Comment: Who said it is a disk?  In the old days, we stored things onto audio cassettes.  And even if the file got saved successfully the tape stretches a bit each time you use it so the act of successfully saving it might have made it unreadable.  That's why you always save the file on three different physical devices.  Don't ask how I decided three was optimal....

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You had TAPE?! I wrote to a device that etched bits onto WAX CYLINDERS! ;) Thx for the historical note. Closest I ever got to tape was [datasettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Datasette).

Comment: Yes.  The datasettes were what I was talking about but I was using an Apple ][ so you had to provide your own cassette recorder to the headphone and mic jacks.

Comment: For any future readers that aren't old enough to even remember audio cassettes - here is a wax cylinder: https://www.nfsa.gov.au/collection/curated/wax-cylinder-recordings